wordpress shell_exec issues
Im trying to use a python script I developed for a Wordpress plugin. its returning the output as null Im confused on if the python script needs to be in the wordpress plugin's directory or if it should be stored somewhere in the database to be interacted with. Right now i have my python script developed directly in the plugin folder.
// Call the Python script
            $command = escapeshellcmd("python3 " . plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . "transcribe.py " . escapeshellarg($file_path));
            $output = shell_exec($command);

            if ($output === null) {
                wp_die('Transcription failed!');

I developed debug catch cases that got me to the point where I know this code is what's breaking it. I tried checking to see if its disabled in the php configuration and it doesnt seem to be. Im using local wp so it doesnt disable functions by default.
PHP version 8.1.29
nginx webserver
database is sql 8.0.16

I'd start by making a debug output of $command, and checking what that results in when executed directly on the console.

I always tell people to use proc_open. It is a little more complex, but it gives you access to stdout and stderr, as well as the exit code, and if you use the array syntax for the first command you get automatic argument escaping. To your problem, my first guess is that the user that is executing the python script (the PHP web user) doesn't have the libraries installed in their path.
